# Scalaz Implicit Resolution Confusion

Tags: scala, monads, implicit, scalaz

I'm running into a situation with Scalaz that's confusing me a bit. Let's say we have the following types defined.

```
import scalaz.*
import Scalaz.*

type Example[A] = Unit \/ Success[A]

case class Success[+A](val exampleField: A)
```

So `Example` is either a left `Unit` or a right `Success[A]`, where `Success` is a trivial wrapper around an `A`.

Now, I want to write a function which is basically Scalaz's monadic bind operator on `Example`.

```
def doBind[A, B](a: Example[A])(f: Success[A] => Example[B]): Example[B] =
  a.flatMap(f)
```

Looks great. Scala's `flatMap` is basically the monadic bind operator, and this all typechecks.

However, if I try to use the Scalaz [`>>=` bind operator](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.scalaz/scalaz_2.13/7.4.0-M3/scalaz/syntax/BindOps.html#%3E%3E=%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EF%5BB%5D):F%5BB%5D) here as follows

```
def doBind[A, B](a: Example[A])(f: Success[A] => Example[B]): Example[B] =
  a >>= f
```

then we get

```
[error] 12 |  a >>= f
[error]    |  ^^^^^
[error]    |  value >>= is not a member of com.mercerenies.fictional.Example[A].
[error]    |  An extension method was tried, but could not be fully constructed:
[error]    |
[error]    |      scalaz.Scalaz.ToBindOpsUnapply[com.mercerenies.fictional.Example[A]](a)(
[error]    |        scalaz.Unapply.unapplyMAB1[TC, M0, A0, B0](scalaz.\/.DisjunctionInstances1[Nothing])
[error]    |      )
```

On the other hand, if we *remove* the `Success` and have our `Example` directly be a right `A` as

```
type Example[A] = Unit \/ A

def doBind[A, B](a: Example[A])(f: A => Example[B]): Example[B] =
  a >>= f
```

then the `>>=` works. So why doesn't it work if we have a `Success` case class wrapper around our value? My understanding is that `>>=` is coming from an implicit instance of [`BindOps`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.scalaz/scalaz_2.13/7.4.0-M3/scalaz/syntax/BindOps.html), so why does it work in the `A` case but not the `Success[A]` case?

Running Scala 3.0.0 with Scalaz 7.4.0-M7.